# Does the KDB+ gateway have to hold all the data?

Tags: mapreduce, time-series, kdb

I am trying to implement a gateway design to access/abstract the api to my database, which is simply a single HDB and RDB on the same server. Reading through documentation https://code.kx.com/q/wp/gateway-design/ the most basic gateways act as at least one man in the middle. Without aggregation this doubles the data transfer needed and with aggregation it seems that to be generic (implement "select" for example) it would need to pull all data to the gateway anyway (for example to perform an average that required data from both). Is there something I am missing in the design of the gateway so as not to copy the data through it, a simple and elegant solution for a small setup would be ideal. I guess this is the map reduce problem in general but in a KDB+ HDB/RDB setting.

Comment: What purpose is your gateway providing? Kinda feels like you could just connect to RDB/HDB directly from your client process (wrapped up in some user-friendly functionality if required)?

Comment: To provide a single api to the data/wrap permissions etc and eventually may move to multi server/process. I want a single point of entry from a programming perspective - although considering doing as you say for now, however this would mean implementing aggregation for each user language. I am surprised that there is not native functionality/simple design pattern for non-copy data forwarding and map reduce. For the second point with HDB I am partitioning by days and the RDB is the current day so its strange that there is not functionality to say that the RDB is just another shard of HDB?

Comment: How much data are you sending through the gateway? Are you encountering issues? I would imagine you'd want the aggregation done away from the client (assuming powerful servers and e.g. desktop clients), rather than sending huge volumes of data to be processed client-side.

Comment: The data is pretty large and some of the clients need it to be sent through "as is" in chunks for sequential playback, hence why a double copy is not ideal. Other clients need aggregated data for visualisation for example. For the second the aggregation on gateway is fine, that is more a question of RDB/HDB integration and how to write generic seamless aggregation

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look on https://www.aquaq.co.uk/kdb-gateways/
aquaq torq has implement a good gw setup. If you are setting a new kdb project, torq will be a boost starter for you.

Asyn gw dosent hold any data
Sync gw does hold data and processing can be done on sync gw itself and then return to user/client

Answer (score -1):

The gateway in general doesn't hold the data. Instead it uses Inter-process Communication (IPC) to send requests to the RDB and HDB. The queries are calculated on the RDB and HDB side and the result is then sent to the gateway which is then sent to the client, but the gateway usually doesn't store the data.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I feel like this is an answer to the title and not the question. By "hold" I mean a copy exists on at some point, I understand the roles of the RDB and HDB.

Comment: To clarify my question has nothing to do with persisting data on the gateway, either in memory or on disk, I am asking if there is a way of stopping the data being sent by IPC twice, first to the gateway and then to the client. And for general aggregation implementation (select) having to send all the data to the gateway for it to aggregate properly - for example the average of an average is not the average of the whole, you need more data than that and it would take implementation of every aggregation to know what data exactly was needed - IE the map reduce problem

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. 
I don't know of any methods that bypass the gateway and avoid data being sent twice by IPC. The best solution I know of is to perform sub aggregations on the RDB and HDB and then combine those at the gateway level, rather than sending all the data to the gateway. So for example, to calculate an average you would get the sum and count from the HDB and RDB, then combine them at the gateway.